# Change product quantity having a list of SKUs and quantities

Tags: quantity, sku

I have product SKU.

using that i have to change product quantity As stock so how to do this.

I am getting a SKU and quantity like this

```
Array
(
    [minimalVS] => 1
    [seaglassin] => 0
    [half_moon_knuckle_ring] => 90
    [unique_Walnut_and_Cherry] => 8
    [half_eternity_ring_Sapphire_ring] => 11
    [ear_jacket] => 2
    [short_Thin_Line] => 44
    [totally_Awesome] => 1
    [handcrafted_Leather_Briefcase] => 5
    [militaryexpedition] => 5
)
```

Key as SKU and Value as Quantity means [sku] => quantity so how to change quantity

Comment: Where do you want to change the quantity? In the cart? As stock? via an import?

Comment: As stock i want to change quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load` method accepts the field to load on as a second argument. In this case that would be ***sku***

```
$productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku([the SKU], 'sku');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
// some default stock settings that you might need
$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('use_config_notify_stock_qty', 0);

$stockItem->setData('qty', [the quantity]);

$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`example`.`mg_cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_MG_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_MG_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `mg_catalog_product_entity` (`entity_i), query was: INSERT INTO `mg_cataloginventory_stock_item` (`qty`, `is_in_stock`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";i:1;s:1923:"#0 F:\wamp\www\example\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110):  Getting this error

Comment: Please make sure the product is indeed loaded. Vardump for example the product objects ID to see if it is

Comment: product is not loaded

Comment: Is the SKU correct?

Comment: its correct i am change this`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([the SKU], 'sku');` use this `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku([the SKU]);` using this only 3 product is load please help me how to solve this

Comment: I've edited my answer. try that

Comment: In my sku some sku name have space like my sku is 'ear jacket' but in my array key it change to 'ear_jacket' so that i cant get my product :(

Comment: Simply to a `$variableWithSku = str_replace('_', ' ', $variableWithSku);`